# How can we import a playlist on mixxx for live broadcasting? (cannot import pls, m3u formats)

Tags: radio

I have make the following files:

1. example.pls

```
    [playlist]

    NumberOfEntries=1

    Version=2

    Title1=Radio Horeb (MP3 #1)

    File1=http://136.243.61.157:8310/;stream/1

    Length1=-1
```

2. example.m3u

```
    #EXTM3U

    #EXTINF:-1,Radio Horeb (MP3 #1)

    http://136.243.61.157:8310/;stream/1
```

3. example.csv (maybe i will make a csv file)

I want to import one of the above files for radio retransmission.

How can I do this?

Comment: Create a new playlist, then right click and select `import`.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did it.
But no track is shown in the playlist.